# Can TypeScript classes remove access to inherited methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Classes can add methods when they extend from a super class, but can they do the opposite and remove methods?  The goal is for these removed classes to not be accessible at compile time.  I'm essentially trying to get (new car()). to not autocomplete .drive() in an IDE.

```
class vehicle {
    drive() {
        ...
    }
}

class car extends vehicle {
    //previous attempt
    private drive() { // can't modify public/private

    }


}
```

Is there a way at compile time (tsc) to prevent car from having the method drive? Can we either delete it or modify it's accessibility?

Comment: that violates the SSP tenat.

Comment: Inherited methods cannot be deleted or hidden. That would violate [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). Could you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish that makes you think it is necessary?

Comment: This is a red-flag that your class hierarchy is broken.

Comment: What kinds of cars can't drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As noted in comments, this is indicative that your hierarchy is not correct. A derived class must always be substitutable for its base class.

You have to consider what happens when someone writes code like this

```
function doSomething(y: Vehicle) {
  y.drive();
}
let x = new Car();
doSomething(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider overriding the method which will always throw error. This way you can restrict that function at runtime but not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to sinalize to people in the IDE would be to add a `@deprecated` comment in an overridden method's doc:

```
class MyClass {
  /**
   * @deprecated Please, don't use this because ...
   */
  override iDontWantPeopleUsingThis() {
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```

That would render the method with a strikethrough format in the IDE.

I know it wasn't meant for this, but perhaps you can't fix your hierarchy.